# Reinit select2 data

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

I would like to re-init data value for region select when country select's selected value is Canada. Otherwise region list should stay default, so Us regions.

So far I have the following code, but it always stay US regions. I tried to destroy and re-init again as well, but without any success, unfortunately.

```js
var countriesList = 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/world_countries_lists@latest/data/en/countries.json',
    regionsList = 'https://rawcdn.githack.com/levipadre/US-and-Canada-states-json/de677490123474288ae2777d04f1728e1f1833a9/us-states.json',
    countrySelect = $('.country'),
    regionSelect = $('.region');

$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: countriesList,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(response) {
        countrySelect.select2({
            data: response.map(item => ({
                id: item.alpha2,
                text: item.name
            })),
            width: '100%',
            dropdownAutoWidth: true,
            matcher: startWithMatcher,
            placeholder: 'Select country'
        });
    }
});

countrySelect.on('select2:select', function (e) {
    var data = e.params.data;
    
    console.log(data.id);
    if(data.id == "ca") {
        regionsList = 'https://rawcdn.githack.com/levipadre/US-and-Canada-states-json/de677490123474288ae2777d04f1728e1f1833a9/canada-states.json';
        getRegion(regionsList);
    } else {
        getRegion(regionsList);
    }
});

function getRegion(region){
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: region,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(response) {
            regionSelect.select2({
                data: response.map(item => ({
                    id: item.id,
                    text: item.text
                })),
                width: '100%',
                dropdownAutoWidth: true,
                matcher: startWithMatcher,
                placeholder: 'Select region'
            });
        }
    });
}

getRegion(regionsList);

function startWithMatcher(params, data) {
    params.term = params.term || '';
    if (data.text.toUpperCase().indexOf(params.term.toUpperCase()) == 0) {
        return data;
    }
    return false;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.13/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.13/js/select2.min.js"></script>

<select class="country">
  <option></option>
</select>

<br>
<br>
<br>

<select class="region">
  <option></option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current logic is appending the new regions to the select2 instance. To remove the original entries you can call `empty()` on the select before you add the new `option` elements. Alternatively, if you want to retain the first empty `option`, then you can use this:

```
regionSelect.children().not(':first').remove();
```

Here's a working example:

```js
var countriesList = 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/world_countries_lists@latest/data/en/countries.json',
  regionsList = 'https://rawcdn.githack.com/levipadre/US-and-Canada-states-json/de677490123474288ae2777d04f1728e1f1833a9/',
  countrySelect = $('.country'),
  regionSelect = $('.region');

$.ajax({
  type: 'GET',
  url: countriesList,
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function(response) {
    countrySelect.select2({
      data: response.map(item => ({
        id: item.alpha2,
        text: item.name,
        source: item.alpha2 == 'ca' ? 'canada-states.json' : 'us-states.json'        
      })),
      width: '100%',
      dropdownAutoWidth: true,
      matcher: startWithMatcher,
      placeholder: 'Select country'
    });
  }
});

countrySelect.on('select2:select', function(e) {
  var data = e.params.data;
  regionSelect.show();
  getRegion(regionsList + e.params.data.source);
});

function getRegion(region) {
  $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: region,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(response) {
      regionSelect.children().not(':first').remove(); // remove old options
      regionSelect.select2({
          data: response.map(item => ({
            id: item.id,
            text: item.text
          })),
          width: '100%',
          dropdownAutoWidth: true,
          matcher: startWithMatcher,
          placeholder: 'Select region'
        });
    }
  });
}

function startWithMatcher(params, data) {
  params.term = params.term || '';
  if (data.text.toUpperCase().indexOf(params.term.toUpperCase()) == 0) {
    return data;
  }
  return false;
}
```

```css
.region { display: none; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.13/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.13/js/select2.min.js"></script>

<select class="country">
  <option></option>
</select>
<br /><br />
<select class="region">
  <option></option>
</select>
```

Also note that I fixed your logic to allow changing between US/Canadian states, as the original logic would always retain Canadian once changed.